# Axios OAuth2 FastApi

Tags: javascript, python, oauth-2.0, axios, fastapi

I really can't understand how form data works with axios. How can I pass variables to axios?

Here's my code:

```
  methods: {
login() {
  const username = this.username, password = this.password;

  axios.post(process.env.VUE_APP_LOGIN, {"username": username, "password": password})
  .then(response => {
    const {token, token_type} = response.data;
    console.log(token, token_type)
    // ['authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`
    this.$store.commit('auth/SET_TOKEN', token)
  })

  },
```

and backend method:

```
@router.post("/login", response_model=Token)
async def login_for_access_token(form_data: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends()):
    user = authenticate_user(fake_users_db, form_data.username, form_data.password)
    if not user:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Incorrect username or password")
    access_token_expires = timedelta(minutes=ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES)
    access_token = create_access_token(
        data={"sub": user.username, "scopes": form_data.scopes},
        expires_delta=access_token_expires,
    )
    return {"access_token": access_token, "token_type": "bearer"}
```

How can I pass variables to this axios to get token?

Comment: It's hard to say what you're _actually_ asking for. You're using variables in your call to axios - although through `this`. Are you asking how you can extract the returned token (.. which it seems you're already doing), or are you asking how you can include that token in future requests after it has been returned from your authentication endpoint?

Comment: I'm asking i think i need to do pydantic model of username and password and then i can get it from axios by data?

Answer (score 4):

```js
const loginUser = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()

        const url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/"

        setLoading(true)

        const username = logininfo.username
        const password = logininfo.password


        // we have to use formData cause we are expecting OAuth2PasswordRequestForm
        // in the backend
        const form_data = new FormData()

        form_data.append("username", username)
        form_data.append("password", password)

        axios.post(url, form_data).then((response) => {
            if (response.status === 200) {
                swal("Registration Successful, you can now login")
                navigate("/sign-up")
            }else {
                swal("Registration Failed, please try again")
                navigate("/sign-up")
            }
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        })

        setlogininfo({
            password: ""
        })

        // optional
        // setLoading(false)
    }
```

This is bacause in the backend you are expecting a `OAuth2PasswordRequestForm`. This will solve you problem by creating a `FormData` object.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i find the method how you can put username and password with form_data
JS can use formdata type you need to create list of form_Data like this

```
  const payload = new FormData()
```

then append there what you need

```
payload.append(`name`, this.`variable`)
```

and then

```
axios.post(`link`, payload) {
   .then(response => {
   `get token`
})
}
```